# Do spacelike singularities really exist in quantum gravity?

Tags: quantum-gravity, singularities

Do spacelike singularities really exist in quantum gravity? If the memory of anything which falls into a black hole can't get out, is there any sense in which the interior of the black hole is real? Similarly, if we don't have any direct records of the spacelike singularity in the past, is there any sense in which it is real?

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3892/2451

Comment: How are you defining "real" and "memory"? Also, just because there are no direct records of something doesn't imply that that something isn't real. Also, Indirect records or indirect evidence is still evidence.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. A spacelike singularity for an observer at one point may be a timelike singularity for an observer at another. What you're asking is about the black hole information paradox, so see http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1038.