# Why can't the answers to equations be infinity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, singularities

When talking about black holes and singularities, most books say that combining relativity and quantum mechanics gives the answer of infinity in some equations. They also say that:

> Infinity is the answer you get when the universe is trying to tell you that you have made a mistake.

Why can't equations have answers of infinity? For example, a singularity is infinitely dense, so why can't other things about it be infinite?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/455726/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167529/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yh they are, but they didn't show up when I asked my question. Do I delete this?

Comment: It is impossible to measure an infinite value. So it is unphysical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Anyone saying that an "infinity is a way of telling you have made a mistake" is being too playful with words. Usually, infinities are a way of telling that you have done something *unphysical*. But that is not the case with GR -- singularities are a way of telling that you have a spacetime which has some physical uncanniness to it, but one that is physical nonetheless.

> When talking about black holes and singularities, most books say that combining relativity and quantum mechanics gives the answer of infinity in some equations.

I am not aware of such books. The reference is usually made to say that quantum gravity *might* resolve a singularity. I have talked about this at length in many other answers, but the point is that the resolution of a singularity is not physically viable. Especially in a holographic setting, if two independent CFTs are considered, corresponding bulk duals must *also* be independent. Even if in an ordinary theory, there are no ways to "give the answer of infinities". A singularity is a very meaningful thing with a very precise implication, and singularity theorems are considered to make sense of them physically. If someone states that one can resolve geodesic incompleteness that can be made sense of by a violation of the covariant entropy bound, I would be very surprised, since the holographic description of the entropy flux through a compact (at least) marginally trapped surface would require that the Bousso bound is satisfied. Similarly, with the generalized second law, null generators of the causal domain $\partial \mathcal{J}^{\pm }(I)$ turn out to be incomplete if the GSL is violated, as shown by Wall. At least, in some sense I would expect singularities to not be "resolved". There are claims that loop quantum gravity holds some stance w.r.t resolving singularities, but I for one have not seen a very precise work on this. Do point out references (that are not pop-sci books) for this. See my other answer, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/781724/365939.

Comment: Thanks! I probably took some of my books a bit too literally.

Comment: Another point to make: black holes cannot have a singularity at the center since they can rotate and have angular momentum. And as we know, points cannot rotate since it does not make sense for a point to do that. So there must be something else at the center of black holes, and it's not a singularity.

Comment: @Tachyon It is a ring singularity, and it _is_ a singularity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_singularity for a layman look at ring singularities. These are elementary GR things that are encapsulated in most textbooks.